# How can i get the values of parameters from query string in aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, request.querystring

Previously i passed the parameters to my page in a query string. Now, how am i supposed to get them and use them in my page ?

I tried this code and it doesn't work :

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ShowParameter"><%# Request.QueryString["IDProduct"] %></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<%= Request.QueryString["IDProduct"] %>`. `#` is used for databinding.

It also goes without saying that you should also check to make sure the query string is not null and that it actually exists. It is also generally not a good idea to directly output a query string like this for a number of reasons.

Comment: But I **highly** advice against outputting unsanitized querystring directly into page. This just begging for XSS

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I didn't see your comment until after I edited my answer. Good point :)

Comment: i tried this <%= Request.QueryString["IDProduct"] %> and it doesn't work. I have my reasons to output my querystring values directly into page since it's not a very large query string.

Comment: @user1747659 You should never make the assumption that the querystring is always going to be short. That is asking for trouble. Unless your web page is in a very controlled environment you cannot ensure that someone will not try to use it as an attack vector. You need to sanitize the query string, and as part of that process you should check to make sure that the query string exists.

Comment: still, the question remains, how do i get the parameters to use them in my page ?

Comment: Well, reservations about security aside, what you have should work, assuming the key `IDProduct` is valid (the querystring was passed in the URL). Are you getting any kind of error? What happens when you try to debug and inspect?

Comment: It works now. I don't know why. I think i was mistyping something. Thanks.